# Word to describe the fear of unknown future

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word to describe the fear of unknown future? Like when you cannot anticipate your future, you don't know what will happen or what can happen, not near or immediate future, but some future far away.

Like what will happen five years from now? You can't control it so you're fearful.

Answer (score 7):

You may consider using [*apprehension*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/apprehension_1).

Comment: Is apprehension related to some time? what i assume anxiety is something that you are feeling currently and thus is the fear of a near future something that you have before a job interview, what about apprehension?

Answer (score 3):

In a given situation, **angst** or **dread** may also apply. **Angst** is usually more diffuse, and not necessarily about the future. **Dread** is more focused, often on an anticipated event.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at

- [Chronophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronophobia) - Fear of time
- [Metathesiophobia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metathesiophobia) - Fear of changes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have named your phobia:

[anticipatory anxiety](http://phobias.about.com/od/glossary/g/anticipatoryanx.htm)

> In addition, two studies reported dACC increases during **anticipatory anxiety** ...
>   Interaction between smoking rate and anxiety sensitivity: Relation to **anticipatory anxiety** and panic-relevant avoidance among daily smokers

If you are hesitant to use anxiety, *fear* is a notch down.
If you want to increase it, there is *panic*.

[**Anticipatory anxiety**](http://www.anxietyuk.org.uk/about-anxiety/anxiety-disorders/other-conditions/anticipatory-anxiety/) may also shape behavior (i.e. decisions about how to behave, what to say, where to go, etc.) in hopes of avoiding a return of symptoms. At lower levels this **fear** is referred to as ordinary “worry;” at higher levels it may become so intense that it can be called “**anticipatory panic**.”

Answer (score 0):

Future is a kind of **abstraction** and is already *unknown*.
You may only feel **anxiety** since it is unknown. 
As far as I know there is no specific **-phobia** term to refer to "fear of future".

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[future-directed anxiety](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=lW7NGHVPPJQC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22future+directed+anxiety%22&source=bl&ots=WQgHpgU6S-&sig=_aKOJB3KoOzYj_XmV5Jed1VSp2I&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=QVlEU-KXJoKJOLyIgfgG&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22future%20directed%20anxiety%22&f=false)" and "[future-oriented anxiety](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Nietzsche_Future_oriented_Anxiety_and_Hu.html?id=r_hZNwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)."

The term "fear" can replace "anxiety" in both options.