# looking for a word that could describe this

Tags: meaning

I am looking for a word that means my nervousness for my future.
In other words i like to know what will happen to my life in the future,
and i am looking for a word that could describe this.thanks and i would be very happy and thankful if somebody could answer me.

Comment: Hello meer77, I believe this question has been asked before, I also do not think there is a single word to convey this meaning. You might want to check out this link : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143759/word-to-describe-the-fear-of-unknown-future

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for **"apprehensive"**

> - Feeling or showing fear or apprehension about the future. [**MW**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apprehensive)
> - Anxious about the future. [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apprehensive)

examples:

"Grandma looked apprehensive before the surgery."

"The rumors that the factory might be closed down made most employees apprehensive."

"Too many apprehensive college-bound students have difficulty falling asleep."

"Apprehensive of the worst consequences, I couldn't go to sleep."

"When we move to another city, state, or country, we become a little apprehensive of the unknown."